# Smaller Code to check if one shape is in another shape in java

Tags: java, shapes, envelope

```
public boolean envelops(Shape s) { 
    boolean flag = true;
  double distance = 0.0;
  if(s instanceof Square){ //check if the shape is a Square
     Point bottomLeft= new Point(((Square)s).getTopLeft().getX(),((Square)s).getTopLeft().getY()-((Square)s).getSideLength()); //calculating the cordinates of the square 
     Point bottomRight= new Point(((Square)s).getTopLeft().getX()+((Square)s).getSideLength(),((Square)s).getTopLeft().getY()-((Square)s).getSideLength());   
     Point topRight= new Point(((Square)s).getTopLeft().getX()+  ((Square)s).getSideLength(),((Square)s).getTopLeft().getY());

     ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>(); //storing points in a ArrayList of points
     points.add(((Square)s).getTopLeft());
     points.add(bottomLeft);
     points.add(topRight);
     points.add(bottomRight);
        for(int i=0; i<points.size(); i++)
           {
              distance= this.center.distance(points.get(i));  //finding ditance of each cordinate from the center of the circle
              if(distance-this.radius>Shape.TOLERANCE) flag= false;      //if the distance is greater than the radius then flag becomes false, ie., the cordinate is outside the circle                                          

           }                    
     } 

  if(s instanceof Circle){
     distance=this.center.distance(((Circle)s).getCenter());  //finding distance between the centers of the 2 circles
     distance= distance +((Circle)s).getRadius();
     if(distance- this.getRadius()> Shape.TOLERANCE || distance==this.getRadius()){ //The method will return false if both circles have 0 radius
        flag=false;                                           //make flag false if the distance is more than the radius of the object Circle
     }
  }

  return flag;
}
```

Hi, I have a code to check if one shape(circle or square) envelops another. I have used this code. It gives true if the `this` object envelops the passed shape. Can anyone suggest me an improvement or better alternate method. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If this is code that works, this question may be a good candidate for [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: this code works. but I am looking for something smaller. I'll look for help there then.. thanks :)